# Reference returning method applied on const and non-const object

Tags: c++, constants

Consider the following code:

```
class A{

  my_method(const B& b){
    import_something_from_c(this, b.getC()); // does some sort of copying
  }

}

class B{
  const C& getC() const { return c; };
}

function f(B b){
  b.getC().changeSomething();
}
```

Since my_method guarantees const, b.getC() must also be const. In f however, I do not guarantee constness and I do want to change the very same b.getC().

Is there some sort of a way to propagate the constness of an object to methods returning references to its members?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide a non-const overload of `getC()`. For example

```
C& getC() { return c; };
```

Comment: Is it that simple? I always thought I could not overload return values. Constness of the value therefore is an exception?

Comment: @Michael This isn't overloading return value, it is overloading on the constness of the member function.

Comment: You are changing more than just the return value since you are also removing the second occurrence of the keyword const.  That second const is actually part of the method signature.

Comment: Note, if the methods are complicated then to avoid code duplication you can have the non-const one call the const one, e.g.: `C &getC() { return const_cast<C &>( const_cast<C const &>(*this).getC() ); }`